# in net suite how to change the calculation of amount in sales order to be a different formula than quantity * Rate

Tags: netsuite

in net suite how to change the calculation of Amount in sales order to be a different formula than Quantity * Rate i want to add a custom calculated field to the formula

Comment: can you add in more details to your question? e.g. screenshots, what you attempted to do, error message, etc.

Comment: i need to calculate the amount based on the quantity * rate  * length(custom field) * width (custom field) * thickness (custom field) * density (custom field)

Answer (score 0):

You would do this by using the custom price level. 
I imagine you are scripting your application so when you have an item you would use:

```
//SS1
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'price', -1, true, true);
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate', calcedValue.toString(2), true, true);
```

or

```
//SS2.0
rec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'item', fieldId:'price', value:-1, fireSlavingSync:true);
rec.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'item', fieldId:'rate', value:calcedValue, fireSlavingSync:true);
```